# MomentJS returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Unsure what I am doing wrong with my dates together with moment.js.

I have the following code:

```
function(value) {                        
  const startDate = moment(this.parent.startDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  const endDate = moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  console.log("SE",startDate,endDate)
  return moment(startDate).isSameOrBefore(moment(endDate))
}
```

The output of my console.log for both `startDate` and `endDate` is:

`SE 15/08/2021 19/08/2021`

For some reason though, when calling this function, it is saying that my:

`End date must be greater than or equal to start date`

which based on my `return moment(startDate).isSameOrBefore(moment(endDate))`, should not be the case as end date `19/08/2021` is after start date `15/08/2021`

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't compare the formatted dates, compare the original dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the original dates, not the formatted dates, since moment.js doesn't know that they're in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

```
function(value) {                        
  const startDate = moment(this.parent.startDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  const endDate = moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  console.log("SE",startDate,endDate)
  return moment(this.parent.startDate).isSameOrBefore(moment(value))
}
```